# I had to share this with you guys.

Tags: discussion

Check out the number of questions and my reputation in this scrot.[image]

Comment: I'll leave it because of it's novel amusement value, we should have a sense of humor

Comment: @xeno Interesting? Yes. Humorous? Well...

Comment: have you seen the news also ? http://cat.www.bbc.com.meowbify.com/

Answer (score 2):

Nice :). I also approve the use of [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/); I had a small widget addiction when I used to use it:

[image: Screenshot of my awesome bar]